# topoJSON is not correctly converting special chars from geojson like ë or ó

Tags: special-characters, flags, qgis, topojson

I really need these **special** (ë or ó) **characters** in my **topoJSON** file. I use QGIS and export the data as geojson. Here the special chars are all fine, still correct in the output. But when I now use topoJSON to bring all my geoJSON files together, all the special chars are gone.

Is there a way to enable special chars in topoJSON e.g. with a flag?

Maybe also another workaround, so that I can have a topoJSON with special chars at the end. Thanks.

### Some Pictures

In QGIS:

[image: qgis]

then exported to a geojson file:

[image: geojson]

and then generated to topojson with `topojson -p -o "world.json" "world1\line_text.geojson"*`

[image: topojson]

As you can see in the last step the special char is lost. I think in the topojson process the file in not anymore a UTF-8 file. Can that be?

Btw:

I had a look on the type of the geojson and the topojson file, they are both **UTF-8 w/o BOM**. So it does not seem a file issue. It is really a special char converting issue somehow. Can someone confirm this?

### Test-project

I have uploaded a small **test project** where the issue still exists: http://www.filedropper.com/test_22

Comment: It shouldn't touch those -- maybe this is a problem with loading the file in the browser? Did you inspect the generated topojson file?

Comment: Sure Lars, I will add some pictures. And telling every little step. Gimme a sec.

Comment: Added the pictures Lars.

Comment: I've just done the same thing -- export shapefile from QGIS to GeoJSON, then convert with exactly the invocation you gave to TopoJSON. Works fine for me.

Comment: Mhh that makes no sense to me. Also the Notepad++ as Editor cannot be the issue. Because in the geojson file as is fine. I'll create a test project now.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with your node installation.

Comment: That's also possible for sure. But I installed it in the normal way, so why do I have special char issues. And how can I check topojson issues in my installation? Btw added a small test project.

Comment: I don't know. It looks like you're using Windows, who I don't have experience with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is really simple. Just **rightclick** the layer. **Save as**. Now choose **geojson** format. Then look out for the type of the output. Here you see it is currently ANSI and now you choose **UTF-8**.

Now you can save and it works.